# Unity animation doesn't play at all

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I'd say that I'm still relatively new to Unity in general. Especially the whole animation thing. It's the first time I'm trying something like this.

Anyways... I have this 3D model of dingus, and an animation for him, but I just can't get the animation to play. I've been sitting here for 3 hours, trying literally everything - but nothing works. At all.

I added some pictures. I hope these can help.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCooq.png)
[Animator Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1YbU.png)

Edit:

Fixed it! The animation didn't work because I simply dragged in the exported FBX from Blender, instead of importing the .blender file directly into Unity.

Comment: If the animation doesnt work by hitting the animation play button in the ide. It wont work by code. There are a number of animation tutorials about. Try something simple first.

Comment: You haven't posted any information that will enable anyone to actually help you. You will need to provide details on your 3D object and how its components are set up, as well as the script you're using to try and trigger the animation. At a minimum, what you definitely need is: a 3D object with an `Animator` component connected to an `AnimatorController` that includes a state that plays the `AnimationClip` as well as a state transition to reach that state.

Comment: @BugFinder May I ask where the animation play button is? Is it the one in the "Animation" window when I double-click the animation in the file browser? Because the animation plays in the preview window in the inspector.

Comment: You need to use the correct state name in `Play()`.  From [Animator.Play docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.Play.html), it looks like the state name should be `"Base Layer.dingus_dingusAction"`.  The "Base Layer" portion might not be needed.